# xhost and Wayland (aka connect to a remote X server without ssh)

Tags: 21.04, wayland, remote-x-session

At home I have an headless PC running 21.04. From time to time I need to launch same app there, mainly personal stuff. To do that I connect via wifi with the laptop, 21.04 as well,  I use to work. (I do not like to have those personal data installed there).

With Wayland remote desktop is a pain in the neck and I ended up with nothing.

I tried then to launch some app tunnelling X via ssh but most of them become unresponsive after very little time. The pop-up "force exit" option kills the ssh connection as well.

Now, I simply want to open a remote window on the local laptop. Since I'm in a secure, limited environment I tried to use X without ssh:

The procedure I followed:

- On the remote machine:

`export DISPLAY=mylaptop:0.0`

- On the local laptop

```
xhost + myheadlesspc

allow TCP connection for X
```

Any idea how to do the last step with Wayland???

`/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` doesn't exist and creating one with the option `disallowTCP=false` dosen't work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I want to start firefox and thunderbird as different users, I use

```
xhost +si:localuser:differentusername
su - differentusername -c "export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY;thunderbird"
```

works for me,
with 21.04 it didn't seem to by :0 by default

> $ env |grep -i display
> WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
> GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY=:3
> DISPLAY=:2